# Retrieving only XML Tag Names in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

**The Short:**

How can I retrieve only tag names with .xpath() in Scrapy?

**The Long:**

I am currently using a scrapy.Spider and using `response.selector.remove_namespaces()` in the `parse()` function to keep things simple.

I am trying to do something like this, but with Scrapy:

[Iterate on XML tags and get elements' xpath in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533101/iterate-on-xml-tags-and-get-elements-xpath-in-python)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve *only* the name of the tags. What is the `.xpath()` command to grab just the tag names?

Comment: Why would you want to retrieve the tagname?

Comment: So I can document all the paths in an xml file. For metadata purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way of extracting just the tag name from a `scrapy.selector` class, at least that I am aware of.

That being said, you can use the `re` method of any selector and use a regular expression pattern to extract the tag name.

For example:

```
for selector in response.xpath("//*"):
    print(selector.re(r'<(\w+)\s'))
```

Comment: Thank you, selector.re(r'<(\w+)') gave the results I was after.